# how can I find this integral with sigma

Tags: calculus

how to find this integral $\int_{1}^{\frac{\sigma(a)}{\sigma(h)}}\kern-2mm      \frac{x^{3/2}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$

Hint:

Comment: I am afraid that the antiderivative could involve some elliptic integral